# About Hyperledger Fabric composer: error when execute cmd composer card list

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed the hyperledger composer tutorial to create a admin card and it is already imported, but when I execute "composer card list" to check the cards it returned this error.

**Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html**

My OS is mac OS 12, and all the relevant environments are latest.
How should I handle this problem?

Comment: Up to now, an effective solution is to delete the hidden folder ~/.composer

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug with the underlying NodeJS readdir function, its list everything in the folder even the hidden files.in your case just go to the ./compser/cards folder in your home directory and delete the hidden files in that folder

Answer (score 0):

This happened to us and We found out that by mistake we have created a file in ".composer/card" folder. Once we deleted that file, the issue got resolved.

Comment: After that, I did not face the same issue again.

Comment: But deleting composer file isn't the solution i think so....because there is other cards also in folder.

Comment: I have not deleted any composer file. By mistake, I have created a dummy file inside ".composer/card" folder.